# git subtree split error: You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree

Tags: git

I have a git repo in /srv/git/mysite.git.

Workdir is set to

```
/srv/www/mysite
```

in git /srv/git/mysite.git/config:

```
[core] repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
bare = false
worktree = /srv/www/mysite

[receive] denyCurrentBranch = updateInstead
```

I would like to split with subtree the directory content at:

```
/srv/www/mysite/mysubsite
```

to branch mysubsite.

When I execute:

```
cd /srv/git/mysite.git
git subtree split --prefix=mysubsite -b mysubsite
```

I get error

> You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.

It seems this thread has related info about my problem:
http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-users-Problem-using-detached-worktrees-with-commands-implemented-in-scripts-td7597786.html

I tried the following:

```
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/srv/www/mysite

export GIT_DIR=/srv/git/mysite.git

cd /srv/www/mysite

git subtree split --prefix=mysubsite -b mysubsite
```

I get error again:

> You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got help in another forum: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60467173/4523359

The solution was to use the `--git-dir` option in work-tree path:

```
$ cd /srv/www/mysite
$ git --git-dir=/srv/git/mysite.git subtree split --prefix=mysubsite -b mysubsite
```

Using this solution, the branch was created successfully!